# Is the proper Rails inflection of underscore 'underscoreize'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inner-classes, inflector

It seems that with Rails/AR and the `Inflector` methods added to `String` by `ActiveSupport`, I would expect that by default,

```
Nested::ClassDerived::FromAR.name.tableize == Nested::ClassDerived::FromAR.table_name
```

But actually `tableize` calls `underscore`, and `underscore` doesn't actually underscore the `::` nested class separator, instead replacing it with a `/` to make a pathname. Perhaps this method should be called `pathify`?

Anyway, I need actual underscores. So I'm thinking of defining a new `String` inflector method:

```
def new_inflector
  underscore.gsub('/', '_')
end
```

that would actually underscore the nested class name string.

So, my question is, what is the proper inflection of '`underscore`' in order to properly and conventionally name my new inflector method, without configuration. Would it be '`underscoreize`' (following the convention established by '`tableize`') or '`underscorize`'? Or perhaps `underscoreify`?

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: if you are reading this and like this question, please upvote it :)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried parameterize with an underscore as a separator?

```
parameterize('_')
```

Comment: so you are suggesting using e.g. `"Bletch::FooBar".underscore.parameterize('_')` to obtain the desired result of `"bletch_foo_bar"` ?   how about `underscore.gsub('/', '_')` -- would that work too?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with *Ruby 2.5.0* and *Rails 5.1.6*.

```
"Admin::Role".parameterize.underscore
#=> "admin_role"
```